# Change back to embedded graphics from Terminal

Tags: ati, catalyst, switchable-graphics

I used the AMD "Catalyst" program (from within Unity) to change to my dedicated graphics card, but now when I try to boot into Ubuntu, I get an error that the graphics driver has failed!

Following this, I am given various options, one of which is to boot into a "safe-graphics" mode, though this is actually not of use because Unity does not load (only the desktop does) and I cannot access Terminal once the window system loads (well, partially loads), even via the Control+Alt+T command.

I can however, use one of the options after Ubuntu whinges (see above) to boot to the old prompt-based setup (i.e. without a window manager loaded) which as I understand it, should allow me to enter Terminal commands directly, just as if I had loaded Unity and opened Terminal...

So in saying this, what command would I use to switch back to my embedded (Intel) graphics?

Comment: That question resolved my issue, this question (i.e. my question) can be closed/deleted...